How can I parse date strings that have non-Latin characters?
I have a function and I want to convert date strings from the user's timezone to UTC. For instance, I have this date Tue, Jun 18 2024, 12:00, in GMT+3.
Here is my function:
const convertToUTC = (localDateStr) => {

    const localTimezone = dayjs.tz.guess();
    console.log(localDateStr);
    const date1 = dayjs(localDateStr).format();
    console.log(date1);
    const date2 = dayjs(date1);
    console.log(date2);
    const utcDate = date2.utc();
    console.log(utcDate.format());
    const formattedDate = utcDate.format('ddd, MMM D YYYY, HH:mm UTC');
    console.log(formattedDate);

    return formattedDate;
}

It takes one argument, a local date string. My logic was this: Take the date string, parse it with dayjs library to make it an ISO 8601 format string, then parse that string, make it in UTC with .utc(), and finally format it again the way I like. And it works. My initial date string Tue, Jun 18 2024, 12:00 is converted to Tue, Jun 18 2024, 09:00 UTC as it should be. The problem here is that when I test this with a google dev tool (which I found in dev tools, pressed the 3 dots, more tools -> Sensors) and changed the location with the override, it works on some dates. On dates with non-Latin characters, such as Tokyo, Shanghai, Mumbai, and Moscow timezones, which has dates like this Tue, 6月 18 2024, 18:00, my function does not work. It pops invalid date in the console. On dates with Latin-based characters (such as in gb and us locale), it works fine.
Do I need to add the locale somehow, in order to parse the date string correctly? I cannot really make it work on such dates. Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

From where are you getting the date? If it is user input, you can simply have a date object instead of weird string representation. Also, "Tue, Jun 18 2024, 12:00" is not a "local" date string. First, it is not localized, as your example would look more like "2024年6月18日" than "6月 18 2024". I think we are lacking details here if we want to be able to help you out. Also, ISO 8601 would be "2024-06-18T09:00:00.000Z"

It's not a user input. I get all the dates from an API call in ISO 8601, and I edit and format them as I like. The initial date that I mentioned, Tue, Jun 18 2024, 12:00 is one of these formatted dates.  My issue here is that I cannot convert one date string to a UTC, if the date has non-Latin characters. The date initially is like this "2024-06-18T09:00:00.000Z but, as I've mentioned, I format these dates. Thank you.

Then, if you receive the dates in ISO format, why don't you directly format it to UTC if that's what you need? From what I understand you are receiving a well-known, easy to use, date format and you translate it to some arbitrary format and then use that format to translate it again... In the translations you loose data like the original timezone etc...

You are correct. I was just wondering if it was possible to do that. I've tried both dayjs and momentjs libraries, but I cannot make it work.
